# Vb.Net how to make a button code working after a click just in a specified date

Tags: vb.net, date, button, timer

I have started just few days ago how to start programming in vb.Net 
I was wondering what would be the best code for making a button code work only at a selected time of a selected date?

I'll try saying it with an example:

I click a button but the command that I send with the button doesn't work until is not, for example, the 30th October 2015 at 16.30 pm.

is it possible?

I tried to make something but I'm not that good.

Comment: An emoticon is not a substitute for any and all punctuation.  More to the point, can you elaborate on your logic?  When a button is pressed, do you want to queue an action to take place at a future time?  Or do you want the button click to be ignored unless it is currently a specific time?

Comment: David i'm not really skilled in english btw u got the point :) "When a button is pressed, do you want to queue an action to take place at a future time? " yea i need this, not making it clickable when it reaches a certain date, but i need that the code waits the date specified for example i click a button until is not 30 october 2015 at 16.30 pm it won't do anything

Answer (score 0):

With the **extremely limited** information you've given...try something like:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dt As New DateTime(2015, 10, 30, 16, 30, 0)
    If DateTime.Now >= dt Then
        ' ... do something in here ...
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Function not available until: " & dt, "Time Not Reached Yet")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You'll have to wait 2 years to know if the function really works :)